# Must declare the scalar variable - why won't my parameter work?

Tags: c#, sqlclient

I am using the old SqlClient to insert some data with a loop. I have added all the parameters correctly but I get an exception thrown that says

> "Must declare the scalar variable \"@KeyProject\"."

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO dbo.ImportedProjects 
                        (
                            KeyProject, 
                            KeyCompany, 
                            KeyCountry, 
                            KeyCustomer, 
                            KeyEmployeeProjectManager, 
                            KeyEmployeeProjectOwner, 
                            KeyOrganisation, 
                            ProjectNumber, 
                            ProjectName, 
                            ProjectOwnerNumber, 
                            ProjectManagerNumber, 
                            ProjectOwnerName, 
                            ProjectManagerName, 
                            ProjectOwnerInitials, 
                            ProjectManagerInitials, 
                            CustomerNumber, 
                            CustomerName, 
                            CreatedDate, 
                            ProjectStatus, 
                            ProjectOpenClosed
                        ) VALUES (
                            @KeyProject, 
                            @KeyCompany, 
                            @KeyCountry, 
                            @KeyCustomer, 
                            @KeyEmployeeProjectManager, 
                            @KeyEmployeeProjectOwner, 
                            @KeyOrganisation, 
                            @ProjectNumber, 
                            @ProjectName, 
                            @ProjectOwnerNumber, 
                            @ProjectManagerNumber, 
                            @ProjectOwnerName, 
                            @ProjectManagerName, 
                            @ProjectOwnerInitials, 
                            @ProjectManagerInitials, 
                            @CustomerNumber, 
                            @CustomerName, 
                            @CreatedDate, 
                            @ProjectStatus, 
                            @ProjectOpenClosed
                        )";

        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        SqlCommand idInsertCms = new SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ImportedProjects ON", sqlCon);
        SqlCommand sqlCmd= new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);

        try
        {
            sqlCon.Open();

            idInsertCms.ExecuteNonQuery();

            foreach (var item in importedProjects)
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyProject", SqlDbType.Int);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyProject"].Value = item.KeyProject;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyCompany", SqlDbType.Int);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyCompany"].Value = item.KeyCompany;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyCountry", SqlDbType.Int);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyCountry"].Value = item.KeyCountry;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyCustomer", SqlDbType.Int);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyCustomer"].Value = item.KeyCustomer;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyEmployeeProjectManager", SqlDbType.Int);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyEmployeeProjectManager"].Value = item.KeyEmployeeProjectManager;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyEmployeeProjectOwner", SqlDbType.Int);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyEmployeeProjectOwner"].Value = item.KeyEmployeeProjectOwner;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyOrganisation", SqlDbType.Int);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyOrganisation"].Value = item.KeyOrganisation;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectNumber"].Value = item.ProjectNumber;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectName"].Value = item.ProjectName;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectOwnerNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectOwnerNumber"].Value = item.ProjectOwnerNumber;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectManagerNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectManagerNumber"].Value = item.ProjectManagerNumber;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectOwnerName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectOwnerName"].Value = item.ProjectOwnerName;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectManagerName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectManagerName"].Value = item.ProjectManagerName;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectOwnerInitials", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectOwnerInitials"].Value = item.ProjectOwnerInitials;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectManagerInitials", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectManagerInitials"].Value = item.ProjectManagerInitials;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@CustomerNumber"].Value = item.CustomerNumber;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@CustomerName"].Value = item.CustomerName;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@CreatedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@CreatedDate"].Value = item.CreatedDate;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectStatus"].Value = item.ProjectStatus;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectOpenClosed", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectOpenClosed"].Value = item.ProjectOpenClosed;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();

                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            idInsertCms.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ImportedProjects OFF";
            idInsertCms.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Could it because you are clearing your `sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear()` before calling the `sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`? Also, you could add your params to the command outside the loop and just set their values within it...just a suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about you create a new `SqlCommand` for each iteration like this:

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO dbo.ImportedProjects 
                    (
                        KeyProject, 
                        KeyCompany, 
                        KeyCountry, 
                        KeyCustomer, 
                        KeyEmployeeProjectManager, 
                        KeyEmployeeProjectOwner, 
                        KeyOrganisation, 
                        ProjectNumber, 
                        ProjectName, 
                        ProjectOwnerNumber, 
                        ProjectManagerNumber, 
                        ProjectOwnerName, 
                        ProjectManagerName, 
                        ProjectOwnerInitials, 
                        ProjectManagerInitials, 
                        CustomerNumber, 
                        CustomerName, 
                        CreatedDate, 
                        ProjectStatus, 
                        ProjectOpenClosed
                    ) VALUES (
                        @KeyProject, 
                        @KeyCompany, 
                        @KeyCountry, 
                        @KeyCustomer, 
                        @KeyEmployeeProjectManager, 
                        @KeyEmployeeProjectOwner, 
                        @KeyOrganisation, 
                        @ProjectNumber, 
                        @ProjectName, 
                        @ProjectOwnerNumber, 
                        @ProjectManagerNumber, 
                        @ProjectOwnerName, 
                        @ProjectManagerName, 
                        @ProjectOwnerInitials, 
                        @ProjectManagerInitials, 
                        @CustomerNumber, 
                        @CustomerName, 
                        @CreatedDate, 
                        @ProjectStatus, 
                        @ProjectOpenClosed
                    )";

    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    SqlCommand idInsertCms = new SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ImportedProjects ON", sqlCon);


    try
    {
        sqlCon.Open();

        idInsertCms.ExecuteNonQuery();

        foreach (var item in importedProjects)
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCmd= new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyProject", SqlDbType.Int);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyProject"].Value = item.KeyProject;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyCompany", SqlDbType.Int);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyCompany"].Value = item.KeyCompany;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyCountry", SqlDbType.Int);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyCountry"].Value = item.KeyCountry;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyCustomer", SqlDbType.Int);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyCustomer"].Value = item.KeyCustomer;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyEmployeeProjectManager", SqlDbType.Int);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyEmployeeProjectManager"].Value = item.KeyEmployeeProjectManager;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyEmployeeProjectOwner", SqlDbType.Int);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyEmployeeProjectOwner"].Value = item.KeyEmployeeProjectOwner;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyOrganisation", SqlDbType.Int);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyOrganisation"].Value = item.KeyOrganisation;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectNumber"].Value = item.ProjectNumber;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectName"].Value = item.ProjectName;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectOwnerNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectOwnerNumber"].Value = item.ProjectOwnerNumber;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectManagerNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectManagerNumber"].Value = item.ProjectManagerNumber;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectOwnerName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectOwnerName"].Value = item.ProjectOwnerName;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectManagerName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectManagerName"].Value = item.ProjectManagerName;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectOwnerInitials", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectOwnerInitials"].Value = item.ProjectOwnerInitials;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectManagerInitials", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectManagerInitials"].Value = item.ProjectManagerInitials;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@CustomerNumber"].Value = item.CustomerNumber;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@CustomerName"].Value = item.CustomerName;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@CreatedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@CreatedDate"].Value = item.CreatedDate;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectStatus"].Value = item.ProjectStatus;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectOpenClosed", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectOpenClosed"].Value = item.ProjectOpenClosed;

            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        idInsertCms.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ImportedProjects OFF";
        idInsertCms.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlCommand sqlCmd= new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyProject", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyCompany", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyCountry", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyCustomer", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyEmployeeProjectManager", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyEmployeeProjectOwner", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyOrganisation", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectOwnerNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectManagerNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectOwnerName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectManagerName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectOwnerInitials", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectManagerInitials", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@CreatedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectOpenClosed", SqlDbType.VarChar);

foreach (var item in importedProjects)
{
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyProject"].Value = item.KeyProject;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyCompany"].Value = item.KeyCompany;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyCountry"].Value = item.KeyCountry;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyCustomer"].Value = item.KeyCustomer;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyEmployeeProjectManager"].Value = item.KeyEmployeeProjectManager;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyEmployeeProjectOwner"].Value = item.KeyEmployeeProjectOwner;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyOrganisation"].Value = item.KeyOrganisation;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectNumber"].Value = item.ProjectNumber;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectName"].Value = item.ProjectName;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectOwnerNumber"].Value = item.ProjectOwnerNumber;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectManagerNumber"].Value = item.ProjectManagerNumber;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectOwnerName"].Value = item.ProjectOwnerName;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectManagerName"].Value = item.ProjectManagerName;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectOwnerInitials"].Value = item.ProjectOwnerInitials;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectManagerInitials"].Value = item.ProjectManagerInitials;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@CustomerNumber"].Value = item.CustomerNumber;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@CustomerName"].Value = item.CustomerName;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@CreatedDate"].Value = item.CreatedDate;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectStatus"].Value = item.ProjectStatus;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectOpenClosed"].Value = item.ProjectOpenClosed;

    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

or you could recycle `sqlCmd` and setup the parameters outside the loop and then just set them within the loop:

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd= new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyProject", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyCompany", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyCountry", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyCustomer", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyEmployeeProjectManager", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyEmployeeProjectOwner", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@KeyOrganisation", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectOwnerNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectManagerNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectOwnerName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectManagerName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectOwnerInitials", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectManagerInitials", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@CreatedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectOpenClosed", SqlDbType.VarChar);

foreach (var item in importedProjects)
{
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyProject"].Value = item.KeyProject;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyCompany"].Value = item.KeyCompany;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyCountry"].Value = item.KeyCountry;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyCustomer"].Value = item.KeyCustomer;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyEmployeeProjectManager"].Value = item.KeyEmployeeProjectManager;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyEmployeeProjectOwner"].Value = item.KeyEmployeeProjectOwner;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@KeyOrganisation"].Value = item.KeyOrganisation;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectNumber"].Value = item.ProjectNumber;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectName"].Value = item.ProjectName;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectOwnerNumber"].Value = item.ProjectOwnerNumber;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectManagerNumber"].Value = item.ProjectManagerNumber;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectOwnerName"].Value = item.ProjectOwnerName;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectManagerName"].Value = item.ProjectManagerName;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectOwnerInitials"].Value = item.ProjectOwnerInitials;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectManagerInitials"].Value = item.ProjectManagerInitials;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@CustomerNumber"].Value = item.CustomerNumber;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@CustomerName"].Value = item.CustomerName;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@CreatedDate"].Value = item.CreatedDate;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectStatus"].Value = item.ProjectStatus;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@ProjectOpenClosed"].Value = item.ProjectOpenClosed;

    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Went with the latter approach. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of inserting in a loop, you can use a different approach, try creating a table and add rows to this table with your values, once you finishing adding your rows to this table, you can send this table as parameter to your stored procedure, in SQL Server create a user-defined table with the same columns as your table created in the loop and use this type as type in the parameter, after this you can do an insert into your table using a select

```
var newDataRow = medicareBuyInBuyInDataTable.NewRow();

foreach (var value in values) {
    newDataRow["FieldName"] = value;
    ....
    ....
}

yourDataTable.Rows.Add(newDataRow);

// send your table as parameter
 var parameter = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>{
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("@yourTableParam", medicareBuyInDataTable)
            };
 return DbAccess.ExecuteScalar(ConString, StoredProcedureName, parameter);
```

In SQL Server create a type with the same values in the table you are sending:

```
-- ================================
-- Create User-defined Table Type
-- ================================
USE <database_name, sysname, AdventureWorks>
GO

-- Create the data type
CREATE TYPE YourTableTypeName AS TABLE 
(
    <columns_in_primary_key, , c1> <column1_datatype, , int> <column1_nullability,, NOT NULL>, 
    <column2_name, sysname, c2> <column2_datatype, , char(10)> <column2_nullability,, NULL>, 
    <column3_name, sysname, c3> <column3_datatype, , datetime> <column3_nullability,, NULL>, 
    PRIMARY KEY (<columns_in_primary_key, , c1>)
)
GO
```

Finally, in the stored procedure, use the type you created "YourTableTypeName"

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[YourProcedureName]
    @yourTableParam [dbo].[YourTableTypeName] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[YourTable]
        SELECT * 
        FROM yourTableParam 
END
```